# SQL Server - Error: sending message

Tags: php, mysql, email, odbc

I've been looking for this problem on google like a week and there's nothing about it, I have a form that sends e-mails when click on submit button, the problem is that e-mail is not going out, the error says:

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Error: sending message, SQL state 01000 in
>   SQLExecDirect in C:\Documents and Settings\1842342\Mis
>   documentos\Install xampp\htdocs\mg\prov_admin.php on line 363

Line 363 has the odbc conection:

```
$rs = odbc_exec( $conn, $query_mail );
```

The variable $query_mail is the contents of the e-mail which is working (I printed it in my page and its all good), so the problem must be with the $conn variable, but I cannot find the reason of why it isn't working, can sombody help me ponting me out where should I look for the problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014728/executing-sql-directly-no-cursor-sql-state-01000-in-sqlexecdirect

Comment: I didn't, I will check if it is a sintax error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was indeed something related with the "from" value in the `$query_mail` , it needed to be a specific string, I guess called from the stored procedure thas executes the send action.